# Union over iterable elements in set comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of unique keys and I want to find the unique character set used to compose those keys

```py
idx_keys = [
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__323:5",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__326:1",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__368:2",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__907:1",
    "1996/a/c_2/51/sr_37_164:1",
]
```

I can do this

```py
chars = set()
for k in idx_keys:
    chars = chars.union(k)

print(chars)
print(f"{'-' in chars = }")  # -> False
print(f"{'_' in chars = }")  # -> True
```

But I can't do this

```py
print({set(k) for chars in idx_keys}) # -> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Can someone explain how I can do this more neatly. Obviously the logic here applies to getting the union of any nested iterable, not just a list of strings.

Caveat: I know doing this inside a set comprehension may not be ideal from a readability perspective, but humor me. I think I saw something similar with the walrus operator and would like to see what a compact solution looks like, also because it might be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.or_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_) to achieve a similar result:

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator as op

chars = reduce(op.or_, map(set, idx_keys))
```

Comment: I like this. You can also do away with the import of `operator` with : `reduce(set.union, map(set, idx_keys))`

Answer (score 1):

For that to work, you would need two nested loops like:

```
idx_keys = [
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__323:5",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__326:1",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__368:2",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__907:1",
    "1996/a/c_2/51/sr_37_164:1",
]

print({char for key in idx_keys for char in key})
```

As for the error, `set()` can only contain non-mutable items and `set()` is mutable (as opposed to `frozenset()`).

Answer (score 0):

Or fixing your solutions and then [`chaining`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) result:

```
idx_keys = [
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__323:5",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__326:1",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__368:2",
    "1996/a/50/18_supp__907:1",
    "1996/a/c_2/51/sr_37_164:1",
]


print(set(itertools.chain(*{frozenset(chars) for chars in idx_keys})))
```

**Output:**

```
{'7', '8', '1', 'p', '_', ':', 'c', '5', '3', 'a', '0', 's', '2', 'r', '4', '9', 'u', '/', '6'}
```